# Network Connections not shown in Proxyman

Tags: ios

I am trying to monitor traffic from my iOS App on device using Proxyman.

I can see all kinds of traffic from the device in Proxyman UI, so I assume its setup correctly.

None of the traffic from my app shows up though. The app works fine but none of its traffic shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Let double-check the Firewall Setting in **System Preference** -> **Security & Privacy** -> **Firewall** tab and make sure that your computer accepts all incoming traffics (from your iOS Device).

Or disable all VPN on the iOS device if you're using any.

Read more at https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/my-ios-devices-couldnt-connect-to-proxyman-via-proxy

Comment: Firewall is turned off. I checked the info. Is it supposed to show all traffic or only http[s]?

Comment: If you don't use any VPN on iOS and Mac, the traffic should appear on Proxyman if the HTTP proxy in Network is pointing to Proxyman Local Server (port 9090). You can check in Network -> Wifi -> Advanced -> Proxies Tab.

Comment: Otherwise, localhost traffic doesn't appear too. I would suggest mapping the localhost to a fake domain in /etc/host. Read more at https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/couldnt-see-any-request-from-localhost-server